# Collisions with arcs

Tags: javascript, collision

I am having a lot of trouble trying to make an arc collide with the image. i found that most tutorials are of circles, squares but never arcs. i would like to make a game where keeping the ball in the circle using the arc as the player is the goal but i do no know of a way to make the collision occur. pls someone help i am quite new.

```js
var objectX = new Array(1);
var objectY = new Array(1);
var objectDX = new Array(1);
var objectDY = new Array(1);
var objectSize = 100;
var objectDirectionX = undefined;
var objectDiralX = undefined;
var objectDirectionY = undefined;
var objectDiralY = undefined;
var thenarrowing = undefined;
var imagse = new Array(1);
var angle = 1;
var bat = 90;
//var arcX = windowWidth-50;
//var arcY = windowHeight-50;

function preload() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        imagse[i] = loadImage("ball.png");
    }
}

function setup() {
    background("blue")
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    imageMode(CENTER)
    for (var i = 0; i < objectX.length; i++) {

        //location
        objectX[i] = windowWidth / 2;
        objectY[i] = windowHeight / 2;

        //random direction

        objectDirectionX = Math.floor(random(0, 2));
        if (objectDirectionX == 1) {
            objectDiralX = -1;
        } else {
            objectDiralX = 1;
        }

        objectDirectionY = Math.floor(random(0, 2));
        if (objectDirectionY == 1) {
            objectDiralY = -1;
        } else {
            objectDiralY = 1;
        }

        //direction and speeds
        objectDX[i] = random(8 * objectDiralX, 12 * objectDiralY);
        objectDY[i] = random(8 * objectDiralX, 12 * objectDiralY);
    }
}

function draw() {
    background("grey");
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    fill(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
    strokeWeight(15);
    stroke(0, 0, 255);
    ellipse(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth - 30, windowHeight - 30);

    for (var i = 0; i < objectX.length; i++) {
        if (imagse != 'underfined') {
            image(imagse[i], objectX[i], objectY[i], objectSize, objectSize); // the pic inside arrays 

            objectX[i] += objectDX[i];
            objectY[i] += objectDY[i];

            if (objectX[i] > width - objectSize / 2 || objectX[i] < objectSize / 2) { //bounding off the walls right side || left side
                objectDX[i] = -objectDX[i]; //changing direction
            }

            if (objectY[i] > height - objectSize / 2 || objectY[i] < objectSize / 2) {
                objectDY[i] = -objectDY[i];
            }
            //player
            angleMode(DEGREES);
            stroke(20)
            arc(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth - 50, windowHeight - 50, bat - 5, bat + 5)
            if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
                bat = bat + 5
            }
            if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
                bat = bat - 5
            }
            //if (dist(objectX[i],objectY[i] )){
            //   objectDX[i] = -objectDX[i];
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>        
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>secondtry</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
        <script src="codingAssignment.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just copied the code into this, because i didn't know what exactly to do for the post to make it work like others do

Comment: If you want to keep a circle inside another circle why don't you just check if the distance of the ball from the circle's center is bigger than the circle's radius?

Comment: @Travis: Please change `ball.png` to a externally available link to the image. (Or add the image to this question, so I can update it for you). I've fixed the links to the libraries already. I assume `codingAssignment.js` is the code you already added?

Comment: why do you have so many `<head></head>`? the normal structure is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Please specify, you wrote "keeping the ball in a circle" as well as "collision with an arc". Which one is it?

Comment: oh sorry that was my fault, i did not explain it clear enough the goal is to keep it in the circle using the arc to bounce it around. if the image was to touch the outside walls the game would be over.

Comment: What do you mean by "collision with an arc"? Can you draw a picture to show us?